# Smooth folded cylinder with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I draw the following folded cylinder with `tikz`?

[image]

The main problem is the curved lines. What I have done so far is this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
%\draw [help lines] grid (5,5);
%\draw (0,.8) rectangle (5,4.4);
\draw (1,.3) arc (210:180:4cm and .5cm);
\draw[densely dashed] (.47,.54) arc (180:150:4cm and .5cm);
\draw (1,.3)--(1,3.9) arc (210:150:4cm and .5cm);
\draw (.47,.5)--(.47,4.2);
\draw (1,.8)--(4,.8);
\draw (1,4.4)--(4,4.4);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I have also another request. Is it better to write `tikz` codes directly in `tex` file or convert it to `ps` or `pdf` then import it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a cartoon, maybe something along these lines may do? When patching together different paths it is usually advantageous to make sure that the slope does not jump.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[densely dashed] (-1,2) coordinate (TL) -| ++(-1,-4) -- ++(1,0)
coordinate (HL);
\draw (TL) arc(90:270:0.5 and 0.3) -- ++ (0,-4) 
arc(270:180:0.5 and 0.3) coordinate (BL)-- ++ (0,4);
\draw[densely dashed] (BL) arc (180:90:0.5 and 0.3);
\draw[densely dashed] (1,2) coordinate (TR) -| ++(1,-4) -- ++(-1,0)
coordinate (HR);
\draw (TR) arc(90:-90:0.5 and 0.3) -- ++ (0,-4) 
arc(-90:0:0.5 and 0.3) coordinate (BR)-- ++ (0,4);
\draw[densely dashed] (BR) arc (0:90:0.5 and 0.3);
\draw (TL) -- (TR) (HL) -- (HR) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]